# How to restore deleted repository on Github and keep all commit history?

Tags: git, github, repository, restore

I have a local copy of an old repo that was deleted on Github already.

This local copy was just a simple clone (without -bare or -mirror) made by:

`git clone https://github.com/olduser/oldrepo.git`

This old Github user account I already lost control.

How to upload this deleted repo back to Github, while keeping all commit history?

What I want is similar to restore it as if it were forked, and to a new location:

`https://github.com/newuser/newrepo.git`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

A `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/newuser/newrepo.git` followed by a `git push origin` should do it.